# PHP: MYSQL to TEXTBOX

Tags: php, mysql, database, text

I have a problem today. Where I was displaying the value of "fldFrom" in my php form from database. And I can successfully display it. But my problem is, how can I display only once even there is a same word in "fldFrom". Like, in my fldFrom there are same value of "06/24/2013" so then when I test it, the result is "06/24/2013 06/24/2013" because in my database of "fldFrom" has a two value but different row.. I want them to be combine as one.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    $all = mysql_query("SELECT fldFrom FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($all))
    {

 echo "<input type='text' name='play[]' value='" . $row['fldFrom']."'>";
                                           }            

    ?>
```

Here's my database:

[image]

*I want to display the result of fldFrom in just once only...Not twice like this one

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use distinct in SELECT statment like this:

```
$all = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT fldFrom FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week'");
```

for more information check it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

**Edit1:**

you can do same with group by, like this:

```
$all = mysql_query("SELECT fldFrom FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week' GROUP BY fldFrom");
```

Comment: i think the OP wants combine his results

Comment: @DevZer0 distinct return one value from two same value field and i think he need to distinct values..

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh..the result are still there... I think the DISTINCT is combining the same row? all  I need is combine the same value for column of "fldFrom"

Comment: @Philistyne Brigid Bellisima, no.. distinct works on field and you can do same with `group by` like this: `SELECT fldFrom FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week' GROUP BY fldFrom` and if you cant get true result then your values is not same, please tell us.. what is your field type?

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh...I already update my post..with image of my database and result..:)

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh...SORRY....! it works..I was just little confuse in my code so many echo I code......sorry again.. and thanks!

Comment: @Philistyne Brigid Bellisima .. don`t worry .. nop, you`r welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) operator of SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fldFrom FROM tbldata WHERE fldWeek = '$get_week'
```

DISTINCT removes duplicates for you.

Comment: @PerfectPixel..not working...all I need is combine the same value for column of "fldFrom"

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by _combine_. Distinct removes duplicates from a SQL-result. A duplicate is a result tuple that is identical to another result tuple.

Comment: @PerfectPixel...i added my screenshot of my database

Comment: @PerfectPixel...Sorry...its already workk..just confuse in my codes... thanks